# How to do pointer work with accessor methods in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, pointers

Basic problem statement:

I have a very good reason for doing some pointer fanciness in an app where I need to pass a decimal by reference.

So I have a class which stores many a decimal, so let's say is has a property as such:

```
@property (nonatomic) double myDecimalValue;
```

I want to pass it by reference to some other class.

```
[someOtherObject sendMyDecimalByReference:&myDecimalValue];
```

But, a problem emerges! The way that actually has to be written (because it's a property) is

```
[someOtherObject sendMyDecimalByReference:&decimalOrigin.myDecimalValue];
```

This fails to compile in objective-c

I get around it by writing the following

```
- (double *) myDecimalValueRef;

[someOtherObject sendMyDecimalByReference:[decimalOrigin myDecimalValue]];
```

Except I have dozens of these decimals and I don't want to write that stupid wrapper function for every value.

Is there a shorthand way to do this in Objective-C using just the Getter functions?

Let's just assume I have a great reason for not using NSNumber.

Thanks!

Comment: Your `(double *)` solution is the best, however it looks like you are trying to work around a fundamental design flaw.

Comment: i AM working around a fundamental design flaw... :)

Comment: Well redesign it; it will make you feel better ;-)

Comment: unfortunately this project is subject to a surprise deadline and I have few other options that I can conceive of quickly... so I have made my bed... and now I have to lay in it. I'll know next time.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use and access an instance variable directly instead of a property? Then it would work the same way as a C struct member...

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
{
    @public
    double myDecimalValue;
}

// Keep the getter or not, assuming you synthesize it in a way that uses the
// myDecimalValue ivar
@property (nonatomic) double myDecimalValue;

@end
```

Then you could access it this way:

```
[someOtherObject sendMyDecimalByReference:&decimalOrigin->myDecimalValue];
```

Of course, the robustness is limited, `someOtherObject` has to remain a valid object when you actually dereference the value, and if you have subclasses/superclasses, you will have to take this design into account...

Comment: Won't you need to make `myDecimalValue` `@public` to access it like this?

Answer (score 0):

While far from ideal, you could make the ivars public. I hate even saying that, but it is a possible solution.

Another option is to create a pair of properties for each decimal. Create  regular property and also a reference property:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
    double _myDecimal;

@property (nonatomic, assign) double myDecimal;
@property (nonatomic, assign) double *myDecimalRef;
@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize myDecimal = _myDecimal;

- (double *)myDecimalRef {
    return &_myDecimal;
}

- (void)setMyDecimalRef(double *)val {
    _myDecimal = *val;
}

@end
```

Now you can things like:

```
[someOtherObject sendMyDecimalByReference:decimalOrigin.myDecimalRef];
```

Or something like this:

```
*decimalOrigin.myDecimalRef = 3.14;
```

Comment: Correction : @property (nonatomic, **assing**) double *myDecimalRef;

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the NSValue class?  It allows you to pass pointers around as objects.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html